# Miranda IM file transfer to gtalk doesn't work

Tags: file-transfer, google-talk, miranda-im

I'm running the latest 64bit version of Miranda IM on Windows 8. Gtalk works perfectly fine for me except for file transfers, it says `no compatible file transfer mechanism exists` when I try sending a file to someone who's running the old desktop version of Gtalk. When they try to send me a file, it tells them that 'the other person may be using gmail'.

I created my Gtalk account using the built in function, and after checking, the parameters are just as specified in the [Google talk help page](http://support.google.com/talk/answer/24885?hl=en&ref_topic=1415).

The Miranda forums don't shed any light either..anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the `Miranda` software. You report this behavior as a bug.  Of course the solution is don't use old unsupported software.

Comment: my very first line says that I'm using the _latest_ version.

Comment: Except your friends are using "the old desktop version of Gtalk" which isn't really supported anymore.

Comment: But file transfer works fine between users of the desktop client, they just stopped developing it after 2006.

Comment: Clearly this problem is recent so it either can be solved by tweaking `Miranda` on your end or by having your friends migrate to `Miranda` or some other more recent desktop client on their end.  This can't be solved on their end if they don't update.

Comment: Installing software is rocket science for most of them, so guess I'm stuck with using a temporary file upload service like Yousendit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the clue is in the error message. For most connections, it won't be possible to set up a direct connection between two peers, even if you allow it (see screenshot below). One main reason would be NAT.

The solution is to use a bytestream proxy that both peers can use and configure Miranda for that. It is likely that your side is the failing one from what you describe. In general, of course, it could be that either or both sides fail. So looking at the other person's settings may be necessary.

[image: Options dialog of Miranda IM]

The second checked checkbox and the accompanying edit field are what you are looking for.

Also note: the bytestream proxies are services in the XMPP ("Jabber") sense, so the names, albeit appearing as DNS names, may not be entered in the DNS server, if you are connected to the Jabber server's domain that offers the bytestream proxy. The canonical name is usually `proxy.domain-name`, at least in OpenFire it used to be and ejabberd it is.

---

Edit:

where to find a bytestream proxy: From the Miranda main menu (the "crown") pick the protocol/account you configured. It should give you a popup menu with another submenu "Services" under which you find "Service Discovery". In there will it list available bytestream proxies for your service, if the server has been configured to advertise and provide this service. See the screenshot below.

[image: Service Discovery in Miranda IM]

The second to last shows the proxy service. Again, this has to be enabled on the server. And in addition Google - from my experience - does some things to complicate for example encrypted S2S connections, so I wouldn't be exactly surprised if some complications come up with the bytestream proxy as well. At least I couldn't see any offered services. Even though GTalk uses XMPP, they aren't completely following the standard as far as I understand.

Comment: So where do you find a bytestream proxy..and does the other person also need it? I'm the only one that's using Miranda among my friends.

Comment: @Rex - Anyone not using Miranda won't be able to configure their end. So if there end is the problem then they are out of luck. The desktop client has not been supported for awhile now.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't know where you take this generalization from, but I cannot confirm this from experience. Running two Jabber servers myself (one corporate one private) I had to support people with numerous different clients already and most of them *do* provide options to configure this, not just Miranda IM.

Comment: @Rex: amended my answer.

Comment: @0xC0000022L - The only other client the author asked about was GTalk and it does not support doing this rom what I can tell.

Comment: I tried this - it doesn't list anything under the 'gmail.com' node. Perhaps because as you say it doesn't implement the standard fully. I'll mark this as answer since it would still be useful for other Jabber-only users.